# Changing width and save it to localstorage

Tags: javascript

***I need to save the new "width" after the change***
(Hello to all I hope things are fine ...)
How do I change the width of an item and then save it to local storage?
I know that in the following example, the code is not enough
But I'm a beginner with javascript
After learning, I knew how to add many values to Local Storage, but I did not understand how to add some things, such as the "width"
This is the code.

```js
const cek = document.getElementById("fxd"),
      bbx = document.getElementById("box");
cek.addEventListener("change", () => {
  bbx.classList.toggle("fixed");
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    background-color: #16202c;
}

.warpper {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #223444;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: .6s easier;
}

.fixed {
    max-width: 350px;
    transition: .6s easier;
}

.chkb {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.check {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #223444;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    //*border: 1px solid #111923;*//
}

.check:checked {
    background-color: #1e69de;
}

.check:before {
    background-color: #0F121E;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    transition: .3s;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.check:checked:before {
    left: 22px;
    background-color: #1e69de;
}

.head {
    border: 1px solid #223444;
    padding: 10px 7px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #1e69de;
}
```

```html
<div class="chkb">
        <div class="warpper">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="">Change Width</div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="fxd" class="check" name="theme" >
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn">Change</button>-->
            </div>
            <div id="box" class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to mention that I like your design! Then about the task. JS offers several functions for the localStorage Object. For your example we only need `setItem` and `getItem`.

Then only the flow is important.

1. when loading the page, check in the localstorage whether the "width" has already been set. If not, do nothing. If yes, then toggle the element.
2. as soon as the click event has been fired, check the localStorage again. And if the "width" has not yet been set, set the localStorage "width": true. otherwise set it to false.

And that's it!

```js
const cek = document.getElementById("fxd"),
      bbx = document.getElementById("box");

// check if localStorage . if yes set width
const checkWidthSet = localStorage.getItem('widthSet')

if (checkWidthSet === "true" ) {  
  bbx.classList.toggle("fixed");
}

cek.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const w = localStorage.getItem('widthSet');    
  if (w === "true") 
  {    
    localStorage.setItem('widthSet', false)      
  } else {        
    localStorage.setItem('widthSet', true)    
  }
  bbx.classList.toggle("fixed");  
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    background-color: #16202c;
}

.warpper {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #223444;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: .6s easier;
}

.fixed {
    max-width: 350px;
    transition: .6s easier;
}

.chkb {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.check {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #223444;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    //*border: 1px solid #111923;*//
}

.check:checked {
    background-color: #1e69de;
}

.check:before {
    background-color: #0F121E;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: scale(1.4);
    transition: .3s;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.check:checked:before {
    left: 22px;
    background-color: #1e69de;
}

.head {
    border: 1px solid #223444;
    padding: 10px 7px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #1e69de;
}
```

```html
<div class="chkb">
        <div class="warpper">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="">Change Width</div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="fxd" class="check" name="theme" >
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn">Change</button>-->
            </div>
            <div id="box" class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am very happy that you like the design
Although it is a very ordinary design
I am also happy with the answer
I appreciate it so much

Comment: @crous You welcome! If you found it was a helpful answer it would be nice if you accept this answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I really need
I'm new here, I don't know much about the site, but it's great

Comment: @crous cool and thanks too! On the left side from the answer you will find three elements. Up, Downvote Button and a accept Button (Hook). You can every answer upvote if you found that is a good answer but you can only one answer accept.

Comment: Yes, Stackoverflow is great! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are having problems with as your question doesn't indicate it. But to set width to an element and store it to localStorage should be straight forward.

```
const width = '500px'
document.querySelector('.box').style.width = width 
localStorage.setItem('width', width)

// retrieve width 
const stored_width = localStorage.getItem('width')
```

Comment: Thank you very much
I need to save the new "width" after the change